# Find the first activity in the stack

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

My application has 3 entry points. The user can start it from the launcher, by tapping the notification icon, or by tapping a url (configured by an intent filter). My question is; how can i know the starter activity?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a value using Shared Preferences that lets subsequent activities (or an Application object) know what the starter activity was.

There may be options, depending on how you want your app to behave, like starting the second activity for result with a code from the sending activity, but your question is not sufficiently detailed to make any but the simplest of recommendations.